# Set document template for AvalonDock DockingManager

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, avalondock

Uses [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) I don't get how to set template for binded documents?
In case i set LayoutItemTemplate it works with documents and Anchors, but i want to set only document template

```
<xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockingManager" DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=Displayed}" ActiveContent="{Binding Path=Active}" >
            <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >

                </DataTemplate>
            </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
            <xcad:LayoutRoot>
                <xcad:LayoutRoot.RootPanel>
                    <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="ToolsPane" DockHeight="150">
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </xcad:LayoutPanel>
                </xcad:LayoutRoot.RootPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot>
        </xcad:DockingManager>
```